# iOS Swift3 unwind segue to view which is not in stack

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, segue, unwind-segue

unwind segue requires the view to be already initiated. Now the view i need to unwind segue to is sometimes skipped. Is there a way to check if the unwind segue will work and if not, perform a normal segue to it?